# Value of local variable is not used? Its not supposed to be?

Tags: java, eclipse, variables, local

Okay so i'm making a simple user input kind of calculator giving the option to add, subtract, multiply, divide. And when i run the program, all goes smoothe until i hit enter hoping to get my result.......nothing happens. and the only warnings eclipse is giving is that the value of the local variable answer isnt used....here is my code:

```
class apples {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out
            .println("To Add Press 1 , To Subtract Press 2, To Multiply Press 3, To Divide Press 4");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = sc.nextInt();
    double fnum, snum, answer;

    if (i == 1) {
        System.out.println("Enter Your First Number: ");
        fnum = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter Your Second Number");
        snum = sc.nextDouble();
        answer = fnum + snum;
    } else if (i == 2) {
        System.out.println("Enter Your First Number: ");
        fnum = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter Your Second Number");
        snum = sc.nextDouble();
        answer = fnum - snum;
    } else if (i == 3) {
        System.out.println("Enter Your First Number: ");
        fnum = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter Your Second Number");
        snum = sc.nextDouble();
        answer = fnum * snum;
    } else if (i == 4) {
        System.out.println("Enter Your First Number: ");
        fnum = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter Your Second Number");
        snum = sc.nextDouble();
        answer = fnum / snum;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Is this homework?  Anyway, *why* do you expect anything to be printed?  You never do anything with `ans` after declaring it.

Comment: The warning is a big hint.When you get that warning, you've stored something in a variable but never read it back.Since you've never read it back (according to the compiler), you can be sure you've forgotten to display the answer to the user!

Answer (score 4):

You might add this at the end:

```
System.out.println(ans)
```

(I'd have placed it in a comment, but I don't have the rep)

Answer (score 2):

You never print `ans`… so only your program knows the answer...

Answer (score 0):

You store the answer to your calculations but you never use it or print it out. The program does exactly what you ask and then finishes. You just need to display the answer variable

Answer (score 0):

> Value of local variable is not used? Its not supposed to be?

If the value of a local variable is not supposed to be used, then there is no point<sup>1</sup> in storing the value in the local variable in the first place.  The "fix" is to get reid of the variable.

This compilation warning is there to tell you that you've probably forgotten something.  Either you've forgotten to remove a declaration that you don't need any more, or you've forgotten to add the code that will use the variable.  It is up to you to figure out which of those two scenarios is the correct one.

<sup>1 - Actually, it is occasionally useful to assign an expression to a variable that you are not going to use; e.g. so that you can see what it is when debugging.  However, you should avoid doing that in production code because it makes the code unreadable, and potentially less efficient.</sup>

Comment: when debugging? For this case you can set watch points/expressions

Answer (score 0):

1. As you know in your program you want to print something using a
   variable ans you would have declared it well and good.
2. But the point here is that the declaration would be of no use unless
   and until you make good use of that variable by using it in the
   System.out.print(ans); line.
3. By doing so you are telling the compiler that you have given a
   respective call for the variable.If you want the expected output
   then you need to follow it.